# ASP.NET Compilation Error (Can't Call Methods in CodeBehind File)

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, gridview, webforms

My asp.net Web Form page keeps on crashing when I add (OnPageIndexChanging="OnPageIndexChanging" PageSize="10") to my gridview. The grid view is as follows:

`<asp:GridView ID="netEventGridView" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" AllowPaging="true" OnPageIndexChanging="OnPageIndexChanging" PageSize="10">`

But when the page loads I get the error:

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> Compilation Error
>
> Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately.
>
> Compiler Error Message: CS1061: 'startpage_aspx' does not contain a definition for 'OnPageIndexChanging' and no extension method 'OnPageIndexChanging' accepting a first argument of type 'startpage_aspx' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

The error does not appear if I remove OnPageIndexChanging and PageSize. The code in the codeBehind file is as follows:

```
protected void OnPagingIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
    {
        netEventGridView.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
        this.BindGrid();
    }
```

The error also occurred when I would click the following button identified by this html code:

```
<asp:Button Text="Create New NetEvent" runat="server" ID="testBtn" OnClick="testBtn_Click"/>
```

I get this error when clicking the button:

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> Validation of viewstate MAC failed. If this application is hosted by a Web Farm or cluster, ensure that  configuration specifies the same validationKey and validation algorithm. AutoGenerate cannot be used in a cluster.
>
> See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=314055 for more information.

In both cases I set breakpoints in my codeBehind file and it was never reached. It seems like there is a problem when any method in the codebehind file is called and I am not sure why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see the event handler name is different in your aspx and code behind. Can you change it and try again?
Change it to :

```
<asp:GridView ID="netEventGridView" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" AllowPaging="true" 
OnPageIndexChanging="OnPagingIndexChanging" PageSize="10">
```

Comment: That fixed it thanks a lot! Funny I didn't catch that.

Comment: I also get this error when clicking the button now: {Server Error in '/' Application.

Validation of viewstate MAC failed. If this application is hosted by a Web Farm or cluster, ensure that <machineKey> configuration specifies the same validationKey and validation algorithm. AutoGenerate cannot be used in a cluster.

See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=314055 for more information.}

Comment: You should post that in different question and mark this as an answer.